# retrieve image from database using pdo

Tags: php, pdo

I stored in this code

```
$image = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$imageName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$imagedata = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));
$base64 = base64_encode($imagedata);
```

It stored fine but I want to retrieve it

Comment: You stored the image as `Base 64 Data URI` and you want to retrieve it ?

Comment: Please state clearly what your question is? If retrieving is the issue, please show what you have tried.. (please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$base64` would be a string like this : `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAArYAAAE3CAIAA ...` and that's what you stored in your database.

To convert this string to an actual image, you simply have to query it from the database, and then insert it in an `<img>`.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA..."/>
--------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^------
                                 This is you base64 data
```